# Flutter - How to navigate inside the body of a TabBarView?

Tags: flutter, tabbar, flutter-layout, navigator

I have a TabBarView which contains a List of items, and I assign a Navigator.push method for each item. Currently this method will jump to a new page.

My question is , is it possible to navigate to the new page inside the body of the TabBarView? Which means I would like to navigate to another page while keeping all my top app bar and BottomNavigationBar on the screen.

Comment: `Navigator.push` will show whole new screen on top of old.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: any update on this, please?

Comment: Use a `bool` variable to change the widget on `setState`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to put your `TabBarView` inside a `TabController`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Taken from https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

Comment: Is it possible if I just want two tabs shown on the tab bar, and the third tab could be accessed only with another button?
I tried to remove the third Tab widget inside the tabs, but I could still slide to the third body view

Comment: perhaps you missed changing ```length:``` to 2 @michealchow